# mysql querying contacts at same address

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `persons`;

`` INSERT INTO `persons` (`tc`, `name`, `surname`, `gender`, `city`, `stret`, `apertment_number`) VALUES ``

What everyone is looking for is the `name` by which they are questioned, which is the same person to question what happened at the same address.

sample;

```
tc | name    | surname  | gender | city     | stret           | apertment_number
1  | Ahmet   | Caner    | M      | Istanbul | Taksim Caddesi  | 2
2  | Mehmet  | Duran    | M      | Burdur   | Adem Mahallesi  | 5
3  | Ayfer   | Gelmez   | F      | Istanbul | Taksim Caddesi  | 2
4  | Durmus  | Umman    | M      | Denizli  | Deniz Sokak     | 6
5  | Selman  | Cakir    | M      | Istanbul | Taksim Caddesi  | 2
```

When I query someone with `name` value, I want to find people who live at the same address.

Çıktı:

```
tc | name    | surname  | gender | city     | strett          | apertment_number
1  | Ahmet   | Caner    | M      | Istanbul | Taksim Caddesi  | 2
3  | Ayfer   | Gelmez   | F      | Istanbul | Taksim Caddesi  | 2
4  | Selman  | Cakir    | M      | Istanbul | Taksim Caddesi  | 2
```

I want a mysql query like this can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If same address means they have same city and street,then you can use follow

```
SELECT p1.* FROM persons p1
 JOIN persons p2 ON p1.city=p2.city AND p1.strett=p2.strett 
WHERE p2.name='Ahmet' AND p1.name!='Ahmet'
```

Comment: @ErgestBasha So what's the information do you want to give to me?

Comment: 'Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'persons.person2' doesn't exist'

I get this error

Comment: @ferhatyurdakulxd what's your table name ,`persons` or `person2`?

Comment: @lucumt persons

Comment: @ferhatyurdakulxd Sorry,it's my typo,I have updated it,you can check it again

Comment: @e it depends on the OP to include the query user itself  whether or not

Comment: @lucumt thanks the code worked. I can query the same people with `city` and `stret`. I have one last question.
 
What would this code look like if I were to create a column named `apartment_number` for the column?

Comment: @ferhatyurdakulxd If it worked,you can accept my answer,if new column `apartment_number` added,then you need to add `AND p1.apartment_number=p2.apartment_number`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, when I add apartment_number only one comes up and the others don't

Comment: @ferhatyurdakulxd you need to update your question

Answer (score 0):

Count the rows per city and street. Show the rows where that count is greagter than one.

```
select tc, name, surname, gender, city, stret
from
(
  select p.*, count(*) over (partition by city, stret) as cnt
  from persons p
) address_counted
where cnt > 0
order by city, stret, name;
```